# Drag and Drop custom function doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, chrome, drag-and-drop

We are using SharePoint 2013 on premises. We have modified our master page to enforce metadata with drag and drop similar by modifying the UploadProgressFunc

It is working fine in IE, however, in Chrome and in Firefox it doesn't. It let you drag and drop the file but it won't load the window to enter the metadata.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance
Teresa

Comment: very first thought: security setting in those browsers, Chrome & Firefox are way better (and stricter) on security.